# Where can I look at English localization strings on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, bounties, localization, internationalization

This question's title may confuse you, but I'm sure that there are English-to-English translations on each Stack Exchange site that uses the English language as a main in the user interface.

For instance, related to the bounty on the profile page, you can see the following:

- for a single bounty:

> [image: 1 bounty]

- for multiple bounties:

> [image: 51 bounties]

As you can see there is a difference in wording: "all" is not used for a single bounty, and the noun is used in singular form.

At the same time, in the English-to-Russian translation base you can find only the single source string - **"View all $CountWithCommas$ bounties"** [used three times](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=View.*bounties) (for different plural forms - one, few, many). So we can use different translation for 1, 21, 31... (one), 2, 3, 4, 22, 23, 24...(few), 5-20, 25-30, 35-40...(many) countable.

Since there isn't any [**"View.*bounty"**](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=View.*bounty) source string. That string should be located somewhere that I called the "English-English" translation base. Where I can look at these types of "translations"? Obvious expectation was something like https://en.traducir.win/ in the likeness with https://ru.traducir.win/, but first one doesn't exist.

The case with bounties is noted here not at random, because to be consistent with English wording we need to distinguish a really singular case (one bounty) from the rest covered by "one" form (21, 31...) as I stated above. Currently it does not seem possible to achieve this via only translations made on traducir.win.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars they want to know where the English localisation files are, so they can see how it changes the text based on the number of items.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars every site has a set of localisation files. They all have an English one, which defines what all the English strings should be in the UI. Nobody is translating English to English. The OP just didn't know what it was called, because they do not have English as a first language and are not an expert in localisation systems.

Comment: @OrangeDog the OP admitted having confusing title on purpose, they know English very well. That's why I find it so *annoying*, in addition to really not understanding what it was about. (And the reason I don't undo the downvote or close vote)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

English localization (which needs to be done primarily for handling plural/singular tenses) is something that does not have a public interface. We (the devs working on the site) need to handle these. If you see things that are off, you can bring them to our attention here (on MSE).

And for your particular case, the translation can be located by searching for [View.*bounties](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=View.*bounties).

Comment: The link you provided already was in my post. It seems that for better localization to Russian (and I hope other languages) the case with "bounties" must be extended to handle 1 bounty separately with 21, 31, 41... cases. Currently it's not possible.

Comment: Each translation string is defined once in the code. The pluralization is up to the individual language. We normally define them in plural, but not in all cases (this is why the search for "Bounty" didnt turn up anything. You already have one/few/many in Russian, so I am not sure what new thing you are asking for (other languages only need one and many).

Comment: Currently there're 3 plural forms in Russian localization: one (covers 1, 21, 31, 41...), few (covers 2,3,4,22,23,24,32,33...) many (covers 5-20,25-30,35-40). So there's no difference between really singular case (1 only) and plural (21,31,41..). However for better localization (and by analogy with current English localization implementation for "bounty") we need to split this case.

Comment: So this turns out to be question about Traducir, but I thought it's neither hosted nor maintained by Stack Exchange itself (only by one of its employees, as a "hobby" project) so I'm still confused.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars traducir is just a proxy between SE sites and transifex.

Comment: Traducir is now hosted and maintained by SE (it was created by an employee, was transferred to the company not too long ago). But it is not under active development.